# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PortfoliosController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I'm struggling with this error, here's my controller code

```
 class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_portfolio, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

      # GET /portfolios
      # GET /portfolios.json
      def index
        @portfolios = Portfolio.all
      end

      # GET /portfolios/1
      # GET /portfolios/1.json
      def show
      end
```

I'm really new to coding and I'm not sure which code is critical for this error and which isn't so I've posted all the code in the controllers page

```
      # GET /portfolios/new
      def new
        @portfolio = Portfolio.new
      end

      # GET /portfolios/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /portfolios
      # POST /portfolios.json
      def create
        # init_params = portfolio_params
        # init_params[:user] = current_user.id
        puts params
        @portfolio = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params(params[:portfolio]))

        respond_to do |format|
          if @portfolio.save
            format.html { redirect_to @portfolio, notice: 'Portfolio was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @portfolio }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @portfolio.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

I'm just putting this comment here to break up the code so i can post

```
      # PATCH/PUT /portfolios/1
      # PATCH/PUT /portfolios/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @portfolio.update(portfolio_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @portfolio, notice: 'Portfolio was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @portfolio }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @portfolio.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /portfolios/1
      # DELETE /portfolios/1.json
      def destroy
        @portfolio.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to portfolios_url, notice: 'Portfolio was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_portfolio
          @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
        end
```

I've played around with this last section a little, changing :user to :user.id but that didn't help, I also changed :design to :design_name

```
        def portfolio_params(params)
          # params = params[:portfolio]
          params.permit(:design_name, :user)

          # user.id was changed back to user
        end
    end
```

Hey sorry! The full error code is:

```
   Extracted source (around line #31):
29
30
31
32
33
34

    # init_params[:user] = current_user.id
    puts params
    @portfolio = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params(params[:portfolio]))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio.save
```

Comment: And the full error message is? also, which line does it point to?

Comment: Can you fix the code posted? It is easy to read if you will post your whole class. You posted where the error is pointing but how can we check `line 31` if you break your code. And also, please post the full error message not just that line.

Comment: In which action you have an error? Add the whole log for this action

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `portfolio_params` in two different ways. In `update` you are not passing parameters; in `create` you are passing parameters. The usual way is not to pass any parameter.

Moreover, you are permitting the `user` param, but it seems you are using `current_user`, so the `user` shouldn't be necessary.

```
def portfolio_params
  params.require(:portfolio).permit(:design_name)
end
```

And call it always without anything:

```
@portfolio = current_user.portfolios.new(portfolio_params)
#I'm assuming a user has_many portfolios and a portfolio belongs_to user and has a user_id field in the database.
```